# jquery и расширение Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Возник вопрос. Делая расширение для Chrome столкнулся с такой сложностью:
есть скрипт который использует jquery
jquery подключен в head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Но Chrome не позволяет запускать так скрипты.

> Refused to load the script
> 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly
> set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Вопрос как его подключить именно внутри скрипта? Или как то по другому, что бы Crome разрешил работу с ним.

Comment: Положить его непосредственно внутрь расширения

Comment: Вы имеете в виду скачать в папку проекта? Но по сути просто у меня получиться что в head я его буду подключать из локальной папки.  <script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
А Chrome script src= не нравиться.

Comment: Да, установка в проект помогла. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт. Спасибо, andreymal!
Установил jquery локально в проект и заработало.